# `Hidden job` info block overlaps the filter popups

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

[image]

Latest stable Chrome, Mac OS 10.14.6

Comment: Can you include which browser and OS version you are using?

Comment: @JohnM.Wright included, but that does not matter. Basically, any browser (implementing standards properly) in any OS would have the same bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! The grey overlay and the popover had been styled to have the same `z-index`. I've reduced the overlay's z-index a little so the issue should be fixed now.